# include docx in document

Tags: include, msword

Straight to it. Is it possible to include a docx file the same way that you would include a pdf file?

So instead of

```
\includepdf[pages=1-]{somepdffile.pdf}
```

I could just write something like:

```
\includedocx[pages=1-]{someMSwordfile.docx}
```

I know that I could just pdf the wordfile (and I do), but I get so many documents and the content change daily.
It would make my process so much more efficient if I could just change the content in the wordfile and then it would correct in the main file :)

thx in advance

Comment: Have you had a look at automated conversion from `.docx` to something else, for example with `pandoc`? The quality of results can vary, but just a thought. And welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 2):

If you compile your document with `-shell-escape` you can use the `\DeclareGraphicsRule` macro which allows you to set up rules to convert from any arbitrary format to a format understood by the `graphicx` package (in this case PDF).

You would need to find a command line application to convert from DOCX to PDF. e.g., [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) or perhaps something like [OfficeToPDF](https://github.com/cognidox/OfficeToPDF), though I have never used it.

Then do something like this (compile with `pdflatex -shell-escape`):

## Pandoc example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
% add new rule to convert docx to pdf
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.docx}{pdf}{.pdf}{`pandoc #1 -o \noexpand\OutputFile}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-]{mydocument.docx}
\end{document}
```

## OfficeToPDF example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
% add new rule to convert docx to pdf
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.docx}{pdf}{.pdf}{`officetopdf #1 \noexpand\OutputFile}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-]{mydocument.docx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Better remove `\pagestyle{empty}`. What if the document contains other content? The included pages will get this anyhow. Can you explain why you use `\epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule` rather than `\DeclareGraphicsRule`?

Comment: @cfr. Oh! As I look a little closer, I see that the `graphicx` package loads `epstopdf` automatically if `-shell-escape` is used. So, you're right, it can be simplified!